# Difference between rc.local.service and rc-local.service

Tags: startup, systemd

I have a symlink on

```
/lib/systemd/system/rc.local.service -> rc-local.service
```

I get different outputs using

```
systemctl status rc.local.service
● rc.local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc.local.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

and

```
systemctl status rc-local.service
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Do 2016-04-21 09:12:58 CEST; 1h 1min ago
  Process: 1503 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 21 09:12:58 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Apr 21 09:12:58 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

Is this the correct setting? And what is the difference calling the symlink service?

Wouldn't the file /etc/rc.local be executed twice this way?

(Tested on Ubuntu 15.10  and 16.04)

---

EDIT:

```
ls -lahi /etc/systemd/system/rc* /lib/systemd/system/rc*local.service 
1980102 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 650 Nov 10  2015 /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
1980094 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 650 Nov 10  2015 /etc/systemd/system/rc.local.service
2891510 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 612 Sep  7 11:32 /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service
2906434 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Sep  7 11:33 /lib/systemd/system/rc.local.service -> rc-local.service
```

Comment: They should have same output, but something here seems wrong. Why `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service` (in /etc)  in both outputs while shortcut is to `/lib/systemd/system/rc.local.service` (in /lib). Do you have an override service file in /etc (`/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service`)?

Comment: "override service file", I mean the files in `/etc/systemd/system/` and `/run/systemd/system/` have priority and can mask the file in `/lib/systemd/system/` .  So check if it does exit using `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/rc.local.service`  and see what the current status of unit files `systemctl list-unit-files --type service rc*` ,  you may add both output to the question.

Comment: Well I didn't notice the edit just now, yeah you have two separate files in `/etc`, so `/lib` are not in use.  They are not linked so systemd deals with them as two distinct services. Are they manually written there by you?

Comment: It will not execute twice because one of them is disabled.

Comment: it is all standard Ubuntu 16.04, so maybe there is a bug in Ubuntu?

Comment: I couldn't find any in `/etc` just the ones in `/lib` from `systemd` package, try `dpkg -S rc*local.service`  also results from Ubuntu packages site:  [rc-local.service](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=rc-local.service&searchon=contents) & [rc.local.service](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=rc.local.service&searchon=contents) . Did you run any script that could generate those files?